# Apply a formula to a series of variables based on part of their name

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large datasets, containing ~100 rows and +1000 columns. Some of my participants (rows) made errors in data entered in some variables (columns) and I would like to correct these automatically.

Here is a reproducible example with a small number of rows and columns:

```
d <- tibble(nb = c(33, 54, 72),
            C1_1_66 = c(160, 7, 72),
            C1_1_77 = c(270, 18, 25),
            C1_1_88 = c(120, 5, 46),
            C1_1_99 = c(87, NA, NA),
            C1_2_66 = c(NA, 1, NA),
            C1_2_77 = c(NA, 45, NA),
            C1_2_88 = c(NA, NA, 77),
            C1_2_99 = c(2, NA, NA),
            C2_1_66 = c(120, NA, 90),
            C2_1_77 = c(170, NA, 102),
            C2_1_88 = c(120, NA, NA),
            C2_1_99 = c(230, NA, NA))
# A tibble: 3 x 13
     nb C1_1_66 C1_1_77 C1_1_88 C1_1_99 C1_2_66 C1_2_77 C1_2_88 C1_2_99 C2_1_66 C2_1_77 C2_1_88 C2_1_99
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1    33     160     270     120      87      NA      NA      NA       2     120     170     120     230
2    54       7      18       5      NA       1      45      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
3    72      72      25      46      NA      NA      NA      77      NA      90     102      NA      NA
```

Essentially, what I want is this:

```
d <- d %>%
  mutate(C1_1_99 = C1_1_88 + C1_1_99, C1_1_88 = NA)

# A tibble: 3 x 13
     nb C1_1_66 C1_1_77 C1_1_88 C1_1_99 C1_2_66 C1_2_77 C1_2_88 C1_2_99 C2_1_66 C2_1_77 C2_1_88 C2_1_99
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1    33     160     270 NA          207      NA      NA      NA       2     120     170     120     230
2    54       7      18 NA           NA       1      45      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
3    72      72      25 NA           NA      NA      NA      77      NA      90     102      NA      NA
>
```

i.e., remove the content from the columns ending with _88 and add it to the corresponding columns ending with _99, and removing the content from the _88 variables. It's important that each _88 is added to its corresponding _99 (e.g., following the coding in C1_1, C1_2, C1_3, C2_1, C2_2, etc... all the way to C17).
But I want this to apply **automatically to all variables ending with _88 and _99**. It's not a big problem that the _88 columns are set to NAs in all rows (I'm working on a subset data frame which contains only the participants who made errors with the _88 variables), although it's not very elegant.

Not sure how to approach this. I tried something like this, with no success:

```
f88 <- function(df, n){
  varname <- paste('C[0-9]_[0-9]_99')
  df %>%
    mutate(!!varname := 'C[0-9]_[0-9]_88' + 'C[0-9]_[0-9]_99')
}

for(i in 2:13) {
  unknown_t <- f88(df=d, n=i)
}
```

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use index vectors and apply `rowSums` using `Map`.

```
# create index vectors
id.99 <- grep("_99", names(d))
id.88 <- grep("_88", names(d))

d[id.99] <- Map(function(x, y) rowSums(cbind(x, y), na.rm=TRUE), d[id.88], d[id.99])
d <- d[-id.88]  # drop "88" columns
#   nb C1_1_66 C1_1_77 C1_1_99 C1_2_66 C1_2_77 C1_2_99 C2_1_66 C2_1_77 C2_1_99
# 1 33     160     270     207      NA      NA       2     120     170     350
# 2 54       7      18       5       1      45       0      NA      NA       0
# 3 72      72      25      46      NA      NA      77      90     102       0
```

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` approach would be turning it into long form, then adding the columns, then reshaping it into wide form again.

```
d %>%
  pivot_longer(-nb,
               names_pattern = "(.+)(\\d{2})",
               names_to = c("prefix", ".value")) %>% 
  mutate(`99` = `88` + `99`,
         `88` = NA) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "prefix",
              values_from = c("66", "77", "88", "99"),
              names_sep = "-") %>% 
  setNames(nm = sub("(.*)-(.*)", "\\2\\1", names(.))) # repair the names
```